# Android constraint layout barrier causing button cut at the end

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I am using constraint layout `Barrier` and this is my layout -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="abcdefghijklkkkkkkkkkkkfghjqwertzuiopasdfghhjkly"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what the resulting image looks like -

[image]

Comment: Is it solved? Didn't the answer solve the barrier problem as intended in the attached screenshot?

Comment: @SaadAAkash When the textview has increasing text, at some point the button disappears. Do you know what can be done?

Comment: Did you see my answer below @Maria? I solved that problem in the provided answer below - did you miss it by any chance?

Comment: @SaadAAkash I saw your answer it works if the text is fixed. What if my text keeps growing, the button at some point disappears since the barrier keeps moving right

Comment: For that you need to use Guideline, not Barrier. I've updated my answer to this requirement and also included the screenshot, please have a look @Maria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the conversation on what exactly what the OP needs, constraint guideline will produce the intended result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="abcdefghijklkkkkkkkkkkkfghjqwertzuiopasdfghhjklyabcdefghijklkkkkkkkkkkkfghjqwertzuiopasdfghhjklyabcdefghijklkkkkkkkkkkkfghjqwertzuiopasdfghhjklyabcdefghijklkkkkkkkkkkkfghjqwertzuiopasdfghhjkly"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The above code produces the following if the text keeps growing, it ensures the button stays on the screen like the following:

[image: constraint guideline]

If you don't want the button to be cut at the end & wrap instead, add an End constraint:

```xml
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

So your button xml should be like the following:

```xml
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

The resulting output will be like this:

[image: resulting layout output]

Now if you want otherwise, like the button would remain/retain its own size and the textview will not, then set the barrier direction to `start` instead of `end` & pass `button` as constraint referenced ids instead of `textview` like the following:

```xml
<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="start"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way blow,and it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="abcdefghijklkkkkkkkkkkkfghjqwertzuiopasdfghhjkly"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOYlr.png)